# "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate" exception in android 2.1

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, ksoap

I am getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate" exception in android 2.1 when I am trying to hit HTTPS URL (.Net Webservice) from my android app. Can anyone please help me out?
Below is the sample code.

```
SoapObject parameter = getSOAPRequestParameter();

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(parameter);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);
httpTransport.debug = true; 

httpTransport.call(WS_NAMESPACE + WS_METHOD_NAME, envelope);
```

Thanks.

Comment: May be you are attempting to connect to an HTTPS URL via and the SSL certificate provided by the site is not trusted by the device you are running the code.